# Replace domain name with asterisk in php

Tags: php, string

I have a list of domains in this format

```
domain1.com
domain2.net
domain3.org
domain4.info
```

I want to replace the names with asterisk sign before the end of the domain extension

```
*****.com
********.net
**********.org
*****.info
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but then why display the domains at all?

Comment: common use would be to sell them but need them hidden until they are paid for

Comment: Hidden from who? The buyer that already knows what the domain they're looking to buy is?

Comment: in our case, the buyer sees the domain's metrics but the actual domain is hidden

Comment: It is **Unclear* if you want a random amount of asterisks.  There appears to be no effort/research included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it like this way with Regex `Lookahead`

```
$re = '/(.+?)(?=\.)/m'; // OR (.+?)(?=\.[a-zA-Z]{2,11})
$str = 'domain1.com
domain2.net
domain3.org
domain4.info';
$subst = '*******';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

**Output:**

```
*******.com 
*******.net
*******.org
*******.info
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/pdlS5

**REGEX** https://regex101.com/r/HPDhtA/2

**AS PER COMMENT**

```
<?php
$re = '/(.+?)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,11})/m';
$str = 'domain1.com
domain2ddddddddd.net
domain3dfdfdf.org
domain4.info';
$result = [];
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach($matches as $match){
    $result[] = str_repeat("*",strlen($match[1])).$match[2]; 
}
// Print the entire match result
echo implode(PHP_EOL,$result);
```

**Output:**

```
*******.com
****************.net
*************.org
*******.info
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/40IlJ

**REGEX:** https://regex101.com/r/HPDhtA/3

Comment: can the subst be the exact character length of the domain name without the tld?

Comment: @Jay it is possible but in that case you've to use `preg_match_all()` and do some processing. If it works then you can upvote it by the way :)

Comment: @Jay **Edited** my answer as per your comment. Have a look :)

Comment: There is no benefit in using the `m` pattern modifier.